# How to convert all the txt file from a dir to csv's (creating and writing to file )and save them using Python?

Tags: python, csv

convert all txt files delimiter '|' from dir path and convert to csv and save in a location using python?

i have tried this code which is hardcoded.

```
import csv

txt_file = r"SentiWS_v1.8c_Positive.txt"
csv_file = r"NewProcessedDoc.csv"

with open(txt_file, "r") as in_text:
    in_reader = csv.reader(in_text, delimiter = '|')
    with open(csv_file, "w") as out_csv:
        out_writer = csv.writer(out_csv, newline='')
        for row in in_reader:
            out_writer.writerow(row)
```

Expecting csv files with same file names in dir path for all txt files in path location

Comment: What is it you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) provides most of the file handling stuff for you:

```py
import csv, pathlib

for path in pathlib.Path(".").glob("*.txt"):
    with path.open() as txtfile, path.with_suffix(".csv").open(mode="w") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(txtfile, delimiter = '|')
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: How do you specify the directory?Cause it gived me an error as  ValueError: Invalid suffix 'csv'

Comment: I just noticed csv was missing a period. i.e ".csv" It works now. Thank you. I am new to python . this is helpful

Comment: Ah, sorry, fixed!

Comment: I just noticed that this code is generating extra blanks rows between every data entry row? Do you know why could be happening and also how to eliminate?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your input data.

Answer (score 0):

TO avoid blanks in the output file just added newline parameter in the above code
import csv, pathlib

```
for path in pathlib.Path(".").glob("*.txt"):
    with path.open() as txtfile, path.with_suffix(".csv").open(mode="w",**newline=''**) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(txtfile, delimiter = '|')
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```